# ASP.Net GridView strange edit behaviour with paging

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms, objectdatasource

I have an ObjectDataSource

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource SelectCountMethod="GetCount" EnablePaging="true" SortParameterName="sortExpression" ID="customersDS" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetList" TypeName="expenses.Classes.ExpenseFactory" DeleteMethod="Delete" UpdateMethod="Update"  >
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="IdHidden" PropertyName="Value" Name="userId" />   
        <asp:Parameter DbType='Boolean' DefaultValue='false' Name='isExpense' />      
         <asp:Parameter DbType='Boolean' DefaultValue='false' Name='containRepeated' />  
         <asp:ControlParameter DbType="Int32" DefaultValue="" ControlID="CategorySelector2" Name="categoryId" />        
          <asp:ControlParameter DbType="DateTime" DefaultValue="" ControlID="FromSpentDateCalendarBox" Name="from" />  
          <asp:ControlParameter DbType="DateTime" DefaultValue="" ControlID="ToSpentDateCalendarBox" Name="to" />  
    </SelectParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
     <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="IdHidden" PropertyName="Value" Name="userId" />   
        <asp:Parameter DbType='Boolean' DefaultValue='false' Name='isExpense' />   
    </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

connected to a GridView

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True"
            DataSourceID="customersDS" CssClass="gtable sortable width100" DataKeyNames="Id"
            AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="odd" CellPadding="0" GridLines="None" OnPreRender="PreRender"
        OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" 
           >
```

with edit and delete buttons in a CommandField

```
<asp:CommandField ItemStyle-Width="75px" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold=true HeaderText="<%$ Resources:Default, Actions %>"  EditImageUrl="~/img/edit.png" ButtonType='Image'  ShowEditButton="True" UpdateImageUrl="~/img/save.gif" CancelImageUrl="~/img/cancel.png" >                                                                      
   <ControlStyle CssClass="my_edit_buttons" />                             
</asp:CommandField>
```

Everything is located inside and UpdatePanel. The GridView and ObjectDataSource support and use paging. Paging works without any problems. The problem is editing. When I click edit on the first page, everything works as expected. When I click edit on the n-th item on the second or other page (greater than one), the GridView switches to the first page and selected the n-th item for editing.

(More concerete example: I switch to the second page, I select the item number 2 on that page to be edited, the GridView switches to the first page and selects the item number 2 (on the first page) to be edited).

Any ideas what may be the problem?

**EDIT:**

PreRender (setting GridView header):

```
    protected void PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            GridView1.UseAccessibleHeader = false;
            GridView1.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
```

RowDataBound (changind delete button to a custom one with configmation prompt|:

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            // we are using a html anchor and a hidden asp:button for the delete
            HtmlAnchor linkDelete = (HtmlAnchor) e.Row.FindControl("linkDelete");
            ImageButton btnDelete = (ImageButton) e.Row.FindControl("btnDelete");

            string prompt = Resources.Default.DeletePrompt;
            linkDelete.Attributes["onclick"] = string.Format(prompt, btnDelete.ClientID);

            Expense expense = e.Row.DataItem as Expense;
            if (expense!=null)
            {
                if (expense.SpentDate>DateTime.Now)
                {
                    e.Row.CssClass = "future";   
                }
            }

            e.Row.Cells[1].CssClass = e.Row.Cells[4].CssClass = "red";               
        }
```

Comment: can you show what happens in RowDataBound and PreRender?

Comment: What happens if you turn off partial rendering? (`EnablePartialRendering="False"` on the `ScriptManager`)

Comment: @RichardDeeming the same strange behaviour, editing the item on the first page